# Типы переменных для отрицательных чисел

Tags: c#

Какой тип данных используется для отрицательных чисел? Например -1.22

Comment: float/double/decimal... Для дробных не так и много вариантов

Answer (score 4, accepted):

double, decimal и другие, [пишут об том тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cs7y5x0x(v=vs.90).aspx).